# Text files manipulating in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a bunch of CSV files in a folder (OS: Ubuntu). All of them on the same structure. more than 2k columns (That's how of got it). The first column is ID.

I'm not able to work with SQL (nevermind why), so i guess i will need to work with bash command such as `awk`, `cut`, `sed`, etc which i have a basic knowledge on them.

I need to do the following:
Run over the files (like the files are merged as one file): for each even column, check if it has one distinct value equal to `0` --> if so, delete the column and the next column.
In addition, i need to print into a new file the index of the removed columns.

Example

```
file_1:
2231, 0, 5, 0, 9, 0, 9, 3, 3
1322, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 9, 2, 5
1233, 5, 5, 0, 3, 0, 9, 4, 6
1543, 2, 5, 0, 4, 0, 9, 6, 1
2341, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 9, 0, 2

files_2:
1322, 0, 5, 0, 3, 0, 9, 1, 2
1432, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 9, 3, 7
1434, 0, 5, 0, 8, 0, 9, 1, 4
1132, 0, 5, 0, 4, 0, 9, 3, 5
1434, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 9, 1, 0
```

Expected result:

```
Removed index columns file: 4, 5, 6, 7

    file_1 content:
    2231, 0, 5, 3, 3
    1322, 0, 5, 2, 5
    1233, 5, 5, 4, 6
    1543, 2, 5, 6, 1
    2341, 0, 5, 0, 2

    files_2 content:
    1322, 0, 5, 1, 2
    1432, 0, 5, 3, 7
    1434, 0, 5, 1, 4
    1132, 0, 5, 3, 5
    1434, 0, 5, 1, 0
```

Is it possible to do that with one these bash commands? If so, how? Any other solution will be good as well, but i prefer the bash commands.

Comment: There are lots and lots of ways do do this, including bash and/or sed, awk, etc.  Q: Which programming language(s) - if any - do you feel most comfortable with?  C? Java?  Perl?  Python?  Bash?  Other?

Comment: As i said, i prefer bash. Python will be good as well. I feel very good with Java and SQL, but i can't used them in this case (never mind why).

Comment: You might convert them to some [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) then use SQL on that `.sqlite` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use awk to skip these columns with all zeroes:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=", " }
NR==1 {
   for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2)
      a[i]
} FNR==NR {
   for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2)
      if (i in a && $i>0)
         delete a[i];
   next
} {
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
      if (!(i in a))
         printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF)? OFS : RS
}' file1 file1
```

**Output:**

```
2231, 0, 5, 9, 9, 3, 3
1322, 0, 5, 1, 9, 2, 5
1233, 5, 5, 3, 9, 4, 6
1543, 2, 5, 4, 9, 6, 1
2341, 0, 5, 7, 9, 0, 2
```

It is using array `a` to keep even column numbers that **should be skipped** from output.

In the 1st pass when:

```
NR==1   # will run for first row to create an array a with even # of columns as index
FNR==NR # block will run for 1st pass of the file. It will delete entries from array a
        # if current value is greater than zero.
{...}   # in the 2nd pass we iterate each column and print if col is not in array a
```

---

**UPDATE:**

As per comments below

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
FNR==NR {
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
      sums[i] += $i;
   ++r;
   next
} {
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
      if (sums[i] > 0 && sums[i+1]>0 && sums[i] != 100*r)
         printf "%s%s", (i>1)?OFS:"", $i;
      print ""
}' file file
```

Comment: Thanks but i don't know what are the "bad" columns in advance. I have ~2k columns and millions of rows per file. It was just an example.

Comment: So what's the determining factor that makes columns "bad"? Your original description is rather lacking.

Comment: @tink. It's a column that's all `0` in every file.  Writing up a 2-pass answer now.  Hopefully with an efficient way to incrementally keep track of which columns are candidates for being killed.

Comment: Yes. Add @PeterCordes said, "bad" column is a column that equal to 0 in the of the files (only one distinct value which is `0`).

Comment: @anubhava each file is ~150MB.

Comment: @anubhava Thanks for helping me. I've tried to make some changes in the code, and it's seems that something is wrong. I would like you to take a look if you can. Where should i paste the code?

Comment: @anubhava What i wanted to do is: `for each odd n column: 1. if column is 0 then delete column n and column (n-1). 2. if column is 100, then delete column n`. Don't know why, but it's not working properly (only the 100 column been deleted. also, the indexes are not been printed). Here is the link: http://pastebin.com/2u8zbjri

Comment: @anubhava yes, exactly. For each odd column, if all the rows are 0, then delete the column and the previous column, and if   the odd column is all 100, then just delete the column. Here is an example: http://pastebin.com/E0grs34S

Comment: @anubhava It's works very well. Thank you very much. Last 2 questions: 1. What should i do in order to see the list of the removed indexes? It's not printed to the screen or to a file. 2. The first row for each file is header. What should i do to skip it? NR==2? the output files should be without the header.

Comment: Use: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
FNR==NR {
   if (FNR>1) {
      for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
         sums[i] += $i;
      ++r;
   }
   next
} {
   if (FNR == 1)
      printf "%s", $0
   else {
      for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
         if (sums[i] > 0 && sums[i+1]>0 && sums[i] != 100*r)
            printf "%s%s", (i>1)?OFS:"", $i;
         else if (FNR==2)
            print "removed index: " i > "removed.index"
   }
   print ""
}' file file` It will dump removed indices in a separate file and will skip header row.

Comment: @anubhava Thank you very much for helping me. It's works. I've just changed `FNR == 1` to `FNR > 1` and now the header is not appear in the output file.

Comment: @anubhava Forget about the header issue. It's turned out that my files doesn't have header, so i don't need it. Anyway, it's seems that there is a problem with the code. The 0 or 100 checking is suppose to be performed only for odd columns. However, it's seems that this check is also been performed for even columns which is wrong. Can you please take a look? http://pastebin.com/L3DtJwSj

Comment: Sorry, I have tried to help you as much as possible but you need to understand comments section is not for posting problems and code. I request opening a new question with sample data/output and I will attend it.

Comment: @anubhava Thanks for your comment. I opened a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32595524/improving-bash-script-for-csv-files

Answer (score 1):

```
for File in ListOfFile
 do
    sed -i 's/\(\(\[^,]*,\)\{3\}\)\(\[^,]*,\)\{4\}\(.*\)/\1\4/' File
 done
```

- provide the `ListOfFile` as you want (file list, find, ls, ..., wild card)
- with GNU sed for the use of `-i` for inline editing (direct modification of file itself)

Answer (score 0):

You can't tell which columns to remove without looking at every line of every file.

I picked perl for throwing around strings and lists.  You *could* do this in awk, but awk only has associative arrays.  I think it would be annoying to filter out kill candidates in awk.

If you already know Python, use it.  This is mostly throwing around lists, not strings, and python is good at that.

A 2-pass algorithm could go like this:

```
# pseudo-perl, untested code
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
$line_scalar = <>;  # read the first line;
@line = split /\s*,\s*/, $list_scalar;
killcols= indices of columns that are '0' in @line;

while(<>) {
    @line = split /\s*,\s*/, $_;

    # filter out candidates that aren't zero in this line.  (string '0' is false in perl)
    @killcols = grep { ! $line[$_] } @killcols;
}
```

Since the number of columns to be removed is probably small, the list of candidates will quickly become short.  Checking just the remaining candidates in each line should be significantly faster than looking over every field to find the ones that are zero.  You still have to read and split each line, but this should be good.  It's *far* better than reading the whole thing into memory and then looping over each line once for each column.

If your data set is too large to keep in memory, just re-read and re-split the input files once you know which columns to remove.

If your data set isn't huge, you can store the lines in memory as you read them, and avoid reading/splitting them again.  You'd have to keep track of which line goes with which file, though.  In perl, probably a list of lists of parsed lines for each file would be good.  To keep track of which list goes with which file, keep the LoLs in a hash.

In perl, normal lists flatten out.  [To make a list of lists, you need to make a list of list-refs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html).

My perl is rusty, so I'm probably getting the [reference syntax](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) wrong.

```
# UNTESTED code, pretty sure there are minor bugs
# You'll prob. rewrite in python anyway

...  # get number of columns from the first line, outside the loop
while(<>) {
    @line = split /\s*,\s*/, $_;
    push @{$lines{$ARGV}}, [ @line ];  # append the parsed fields to the list of lines for the current file

    # filter out candidates that aren't zero in this line.  (string '0' is false in perl)
    @killcols = grep { ! $line[$_] } @killcols;
}

#my @keepcols;
#foreach my $col (1..$maxcol) {
#    push @keepcols, $col if ! grep { $col == $_ } @killcols;
#}
# IDK if this is the most efficient way to invert a set
# In any case, actually storing a list of all the column numbers *to* print
# is probably slower than looping over the ranges between @killcol.

foreach my $f (@ARGV) {
    open OUTFILE, ">", "$f.new" or die "error opening $f.new: $!";
    foreach my $lref (@$lines{$f}) {
        my $printcol = 0;
        foreach my $kcol (@killcols) {
            # FIXME: delimiter logic is probably not bulletproof e.g. when the last killed column = maxcol
            print(OUTFILE, join(', ', $lref->[$printcol .. $kcol-1]) );
            print OUTFILE, ', ';
            $printcol = $kcol+1;    # skip the killed column
        }
        print(OUTFILE, join(', ', $lref->[$printcol .. $maxcol] ), "\n");
        # no trailing ", " for the last one.
        # Could append $maxcol+1 to @killcols, since I think the delimiter logic needs fixing anyway.
    }
    close OUTFILE;
    # close "$f.new", and if there weren't any I/O errors, rename it over "$f"
}
```