# Improving a bash script for csv files

Tags: bash, awk

I have a bunch of CSV files in a folder. All of them on the same structure. more than 2k columns. The first column is ID.

I need to do the following for each file: 
For each n **odd** column (except the first column), do the following:

- If `n` value is 0, for all of the rows, then delete the `n` column and also `n-1` column
- If `n` value is 100, for all of the rows, then delete the n column
- print the indexes of the removed columns

I have the following code:

```
for f in *.csv; do
        awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
        NR==1 {
      for (i=3; i<=NF; i+=2)
         a[i]
     }FNR==NR {
           for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
              sums[i] += $i;
           ++r;
           next
        } {
           for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
              if (sums[i] > 0 && sums[i+1]>0 && sums[i] != 100*r)
                 printf "%s%s", (i>1)?OFS:"", $i;
              else print "removed index: " i > "removed.index"
              print ""
   }' "$f"  "$f" > "new_$f"
done
```

For some reason the ID column (first column) is been removed.

Input:

```
23232,0,0,5,0,1,100,3,0,33,100
21232,0,0,5,0,1,100,3,0,33,100
23132,0,0,5,0,1,100,3,0,33,100
23212,0,0,5,0,1,100,3,0,33,100
24232,0,0,5,0,1,100,3,0,33,100
27232,0,0,5,0,1,100,3,0,33,100
```

Current output (bad):

```
,1,33
,1,33
,1,33
,1,33
,1,33
,1,33
```

Expected output:

```
23232,1,33
21232,1,33
23132,1,33
23212,1,33
24232,1,33
27232,1,33
```

Can anyone check what is the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to skip first column from the logic to check for 0 in previous column:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","; out=ARGV[1] ".removed.index"}
FNR==NR {
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
      sums[i] += $i;
   ++r;
   next
} FNR==1 {
   for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) {
      if (sums[i] == 0) {
         if (i-1 in sums) {
            delete sums[i-1];
            print "removed index: " (i-1) > out
         }
         delete sums[i];
         print "removed index: " i > out
      } else if (sums[i] == 100*r) {
         delete sums[i];
         print "removed index: " i > out
      }
   }
} {
   printf "%s", $1
   for (i=2; i<=NF; i++)
      if (i in sums)
         printf "%s%s", OFS, $i;
   printf "%s", ORS
} END{close(out)}' file file
```

**Output:**

```
23232,1,33
21232,1,33
23132,1,33
23212,1,33
24232,1,33
27232,1,33
```

Also removed indices is:

```
cat file.removed.index

cat removed.index
removed index: 2
removed index: 3
removed index: 4
removed index: 5
removed index: 7
removed index: 8
removed index: 9
removed index: 11
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes, the output csv file is now correct. However, there is an issue with the indexes printing. According to the indexes file of the above example, the removed indexes are: 8, 9, 11, but it's suppose to be 2,3,4,5,7,8,9,11.

Comment: Now it's fine. Thank you very much for your help. One last small thing - i wan't that the file name of removed.index will be named according to the original file name: `originalFileName.removed.index`. Currently the file is overwritten time after time. I've tried to use `${f}_removed.index` but it doesn't works.

Comment: You are awesome. Thank you very much for you help. I learned a lot from you. Hope to be good as you one day :)